# For Each Loop With If Statement - Performance

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, performance, c#-4.0

I am having a complex object, and I am trying to loop through the objects and add to an another list.

But as I have few if statements inside the loop to check whether the object inside is null OR not, the iteration is taking lot of time. Also I am looping through around 70000 items.

Below is the code,

```
var Product = model; //complex object
Parallel.ForEach({model, product => {
    if(product.Type != null)//type a
     {  A = a.Loca;//do something }

    if(product.Type != null)//type b
     {  B = b.Loca;//do something }

   if(product.Type != null)//type c
     {  A = c.Loca;//do something }

   dataAsset.Push(new assetItems(A, B, C));
}
});
```

I am trying to improve the performance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am checking for different objects inside the loop

Comment: Your if condition is same in three cases. Is it a typo? Perhaps something more closer to what those conditions do will help

Comment: @danish I am getting there respective properties and pushing them to the list inside the if statement, and have updated the code accordingly. Please check

Comment: do you see this 3 times in your code? product.Type != null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Elvis operator I was able to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Improve the performance by only checking if product.Type != null once. You do not need to check it three separate times. i.e.

```
Parallel.ForEach({model, product => {
    if(product.Type != null)
     {  a;//do something
        b;//do something
        c;//do something 
     }
   dataAsset.Push(new assetItems(a, b, c));
}
```

Comment: thanks for fast reply I am having three if statements as I am having three different Types inside the iterating item

Comment: Please know that if you ask general questions you will get general answers. This answer is perfectly fine *for the code you posted*. If you have more complex or different code (aka a more *specific* question), then please change your code in the question. If you want a more specific answer you need to post a more specific question.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Please review the code with the comments and explanation, and let me know the reason for down voting the question!

Comment: I downvoted your question because you are commenting that a general answer to a general question isn't specific enough. Add some **real** criteria and **then** we can get more specific answers.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I have mentioned in the comments that I am checking for different types inside if statements, can you please let know what is general here